# React [create-react-app] in MERN stack project is giving dependency tlel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, npm

I am trying to follow the onlinecodeacademy online course for free to learn MERN. I am having trouble both using npx and installing it. When I try to install npx I receive the following errors:

```
[noah@Qyain restaurant-reviews]$ npm install npx
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/noah/package-lock.json
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/noah/package-lock.json'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/noah/package-lock.json'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/noah/package-lock.json'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/noah/.npm/_logs/2022-06-14T15_09_30_848Z-debug-0.log
[noah@Qyain restaurant-reviews]$ sudo npm install npx
[sudo] password for noah: 

changed 21 packages, and audited 2362 packages in 20s

77 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

107 vulnerabilities (16 low, 32 moderate, 50 high, 9 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
[noah@Qyain restaurant-reviews]$
```

Upon trying to install create-react-app, react and other programs I receive:

```
[noah@Qyain restaurant-reviews]$ sudo npm install react create-react-app 

up to date, audited 2362 packages in 7s

77 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

107 vulnerabilities (16 low, 32 moderate, 50 high, 9 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
[noah@Qyain restaurant-reviews]$ sudo   npm audit fix --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit fix ajv@4.11.8 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv
npm WARN audit fix ajv@4.11.8 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ajv@4.11.8 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix ajv@4.11.8 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ajv@4.11.8 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/ansi-regex
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansi-regex
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/strip-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix bl@1.2.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/tar-stream/node_modules/bl
npm WARN audit fix bl@1.2.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix bl@1.2.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix bl@1.2.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix bl@1.2.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/chownr
npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix chownr@1.0.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix cryptiles@2.0.5 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/cryptiles
npm WARN audit fix cryptiles@2.0.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix cryptiles@2.0.5 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix cryptiles@2.0.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix cryptiles@2.0.5 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/http-proxy-agent/node_modules/debug
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/node_modules/debug
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix debug@2.6.8 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/registry-auth-token/node_modules/rc/node_modules/deep-extend
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/registry-url/node_modules/rc/node_modules/deep-extend
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix deep-extend@0.4.2 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.2.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/dot-prop
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.2.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.2.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.2.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.2.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.1.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/dot-prop
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.1.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.1.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.1.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix dot-prop@4.1.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix extend@3.0.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/extend
npm WARN audit fix extend@3.0.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix extend@3.0.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix extend@3.0.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix extend@3.0.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix fstream@1.0.11 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream
npm WARN audit fix fstream@1.0.11 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix fstream@1.0.11 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix fstream@1.0.11 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix fstream@1.0.11 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix hawk@3.1.3 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk
npm WARN audit fix hawk@3.1.3 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix hawk@3.1.3 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix hawk@3.1.3 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix hawk@3.1.3 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix hoek@2.16.3 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/hoek
npm WARN audit fix hoek@2.16.3 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix hoek@2.16.3 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix hoek@2.16.3 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix hoek@2.16.3 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.8.5 node_modules/npx/node_modules/hosted-git-info
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.8.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.8.5 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.8.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.8.5 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.5.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/hosted-git-info
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.5.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.5.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.5.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix hosted-git-info@2.5.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix http-proxy-agent@2.0.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/http-proxy-agent
npm WARN audit fix http-proxy-agent@2.0.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix http-proxy-agent@2.0.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix http-proxy-agent@2.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix http-proxy-agent@2.0.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix https-proxy-agent@2.0.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/https-proxy-agent
npm WARN audit fix https-proxy-agent@2.0.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix https-proxy-agent@2.0.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix https-proxy-agent@2.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix https-proxy-agent@2.0.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 node_modules/npx/node_modules/ini
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.4 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ini
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.4 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.4 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.4 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.4 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/jsprim/node_modules/json-schema
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/registry-auth-token/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/registry-url/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix npm@5.1.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix npm@5.1.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix npm@5.1.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix npm@5.1.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix npm@5.1.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix npm-user-validate@1.0.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-user-validate
npm WARN audit fix npm-user-validate@1.0.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix npm-user-validate@1.0.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix npm-user-validate@1.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix npm-user-validate@1.0.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix sshpk@1.13.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk
npm WARN audit fix sshpk@1.13.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix sshpk@1.13.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix sshpk@1.13.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix sshpk@1.13.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix ssri@4.1.6 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ssri
npm WARN audit fix ssri@4.1.6 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ssri@4.1.6 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix ssri@4.1.6 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ssri@4.1.6 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix stringstream@0.0.5 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/stringstream
npm WARN audit fix stringstream@0.0.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix stringstream@0.0.5 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix stringstream@0.0.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix stringstream@0.0.5 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix tar@2.2.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar
npm WARN audit fix tar@2.2.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix tar@2.2.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix tar@2.2.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix tar@2.2.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix tar-fs@1.15.3 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/tar-fs
npm WARN audit fix tar-fs@1.15.3 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix tar-fs@1.15.3 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix tar-fs@1.15.3 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix tar-fs@1.15.3 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix tough-cookie@2.3.2 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie
npm WARN audit fix tough-cookie@2.3.2 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix tough-cookie@2.3.2 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix tough-cookie@2.3.2 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix tough-cookie@2.3.2 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/y18n
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/y18n
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix y18n@3.2.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix y18n@4.0.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/y18n
npm WARN audit fix y18n@4.0.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix y18n@4.0.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix y18n@4.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix y18n@4.0.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix yargs-parser@9.0.2 node_modules/npx/node_modules/yargs-parser
npm WARN audit fix yargs-parser@9.0.2 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix yargs-parser@9.0.2 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix yargs-parser@9.0.2 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix yargs-parser@9.0.2 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix har-validator@4.2.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator
npm WARN audit fix har-validator@4.2.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix har-validator@4.2.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix har-validator@4.2.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix har-validator@4.2.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/registry-auth-token/node_modules/rc
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/registry-url/node_modules/rc
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix rc@1.2.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix request@2.81.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request
npm WARN audit fix request@2.81.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix request@2.81.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix request@2.81.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix request@2.81.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix boom@2.10.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/boom
npm WARN audit fix boom@2.10.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix boom@2.10.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix boom@2.10.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix boom@2.10.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix sntp@1.0.9 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/sntp
npm WARN audit fix sntp@1.0.9 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix sntp@1.0.9 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix sntp@1.0.9 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix sntp@1.0.9 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/jsprim
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix cacache@9.2.9 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache
npm WARN audit fix cacache@9.2.9 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix cacache@9.2.9 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix cacache@9.2.9 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix cacache@9.2.9 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix make-fetch-happen@2.4.13 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen
npm WARN audit fix make-fetch-happen@2.4.13 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix make-fetch-happen@2.4.13 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix make-fetch-happen@2.4.13 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix make-fetch-happen@2.4.13 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix npm-registry-client@8.4.0 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client
npm WARN audit fix npm-registry-client@8.4.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix npm-registry-client@8.4.0 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix npm-registry-client@8.4.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix npm-registry-client@8.4.0 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix pacote@2.7.38 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote
npm WARN audit fix pacote@2.7.38 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix pacote@2.7.38 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix pacote@2.7.38 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix pacote@2.7.38 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix node-gyp@3.6.2 node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp
npm WARN audit fix node-gyp@3.6.2 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix node-gyp@3.6.2 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix node-gyp@3.6.2 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix node-gyp@3.6.2 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix yargs@11.1.1 node_modules/npx/node_modules/yargs
npm WARN audit fix yargs@11.1.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix yargs@11.1.1 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix yargs@11.1.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix yargs@11.1.1 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.2 node_modules/npx/node_modules/libnpx
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.2 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.2 npx@10.2.2 at node_modules/npx
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.2 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.2 Check for updates to the npx package.
npm WARN audit Updating npx to 3.0.0,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN audit Updating react-scripts to 5.0.1,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN audit Updating create-react-app to 1.2.1,which is a SemVer major change.

added 533 packages, removed 1327 packages, changed 446 packages, and audited 1600 packages in 52s

198 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

deep-extend  <0.5.1
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in deep-extend - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hr2v-3952-633q
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/npx/node_modules/deep-extend
  rc  0.1.0 - 1.2.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of deep-extend
  node_modules/npx/node_modules/rc

dot-prop  <4.2.1
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in dot-prop - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ff7x-qrg7-qggm
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/npx/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/dot-prop

hosted-git-info  <2.8.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in hosted-git-info - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-43f8-2h32-f4cj
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/npx/node_modules/hosted-git-info

ini  <1.3.6
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-qqgx-2p2h-9c37
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/npx/node_modules/ini

mem  <4.0.0
Severity: moderate
Denial of Service in mem - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4xcv-9jjx-gfj3
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install npx@10.2.2, which is a breaking change
node_modules/npx/node_modules/mem
  os-locale  2.0.0 - 3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of mem
  node_modules/npx/node_modules/os-locale
    yargs  8.0.0-candidate.0 - 12.0.5
    Depends on vulnerable versions of os-locale
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
    node_modules/npx/node_modules/yargs
      npx  1.0.0 - 8.1.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
      node_modules/npx

minimist  <=1.2.5
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in minimist - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-xvch-5gv4-984h
Prototype Pollution in minimist - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-vh95-rmgr-6w4m
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/npx/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

y18n  <3.2.2
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in y18n - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c4w7-xm78-47vh
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/npx/node_modules/y18n

yargs-parser  6.0.0 - 13.1.1
Severity: moderate
Prototype Pollution in yargs-parser - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p9pc-299p-vxgp
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install npx@10.2.2, which is a breaking change
node_modules/npx/node_modules/yargs-parser
  yargs  8.0.0-candidate.0 - 12.0.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of os-locale
  Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
  node_modules/npx/node_modules/yargs
    npx  1.0.0 - 8.1.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/npx

18 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 9 high, 3 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

It is essentially dependency hell and deprecation gone wild.

This is madness, I am merely a messenger, a student trying to study!
**npx/npm/node::**https://c.tenor.com/Lssr-Q7nzTkAAAAC/kick-sparta.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `npx` comes preinstalled already with NodeJS. Anyway, the problem installing it with `npm install npx` is that it's trying to install it on the local project. Try to install it like `sudo npm install -g npx` (Notice both `sudo` and the `-g` option) to get the `npx` installed globally.

Also, about the `create-react-app` please [follow the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) that says to run it with `npx create-react-app qyain-restaurant-reviews` (Looks like this is why you're asking how to install `npx` in the first place).

Finally, you should initialize a NodeJS project first before trying to install something local. A NodeJS project should have a `package.json` in its root folder. And to initialize the project and create a base `package.json` you just need to run `npm init` and follow the questions asked. That's another reason why you're having the first error because  `npm` is looking for the `package.json` recursively on the parent folders and it gets one in your home folder `home/noah`.

Comment: Thank you, I am not the smartest and a lot of this information deals with crystalized knowledge and intelligence aka memory and design v.s. what I need to solve algos/ds.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed node ,type `npx create-react-app@latest yourappname` and hit enter.this might make a react app for you.